# How can I add a custom toggle button to a custom item delegate?

Tags: c++, qt

I have a custom item delegate that I would like to draw/attach a custom toggle button (see image), ideally replace the buttons on the delegate with the custom toggle button. Both classes (custom item delegate and custom toggle button) work fine on their own, however, how to attach the toggle button to the delegate is quite a challenge. Any suggestions would be very helpful.

This is the code section that draws the button:

```
void CustomDelegate::drawButton(QStyleOptionButton& opt, const QPoint& p, QPainter* painter) const
{
    QStyle* style = QApplication::style();
    opt.text = "button";
    if(style){
        style->drawControl(QStyle::CE_PushButton, &opt, painter);
    opt.state &= ~QStyle::State_Sunken;
    opt.rect.translate(opt.rect.width() + offset_button, 0);
    }
}
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

you could achieve this by using a custom editor for the cell and opening a persistent editor on it.

In your item delegate, you'd need to reimplement the [createEditor](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qabstractitemdelegate.html#createEditor), [setEditorData](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qabstractitemdelegate.html#setEditorData) and [setModelData](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qabstractitemdelegate.html#setModelData) methods to create your custom toggle button, set its state according to the model data and write its state back to the model upon change.

With this method, you wouldn't need to draw the button yourself in the delegate because it's not just an image that gets displayed, but a fully functioning button.

https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qtwidgets-itemviews-stardelegate-example.html is an example that should get you started.